# Possible reason that a key is in multiple partition in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am attempting to reduce traffic to our persistent layer by merging updates with the same keys. The updates are coming from kafka.

What is interesting is that I found out when I have multiple consumer, each consumer has upward of 10% dup keys, but if I only have 1 consumer the dup keys increases to 40-50%.

I suspect that some key went to multiple partition, and indeed after sampling I found out that a consistent portion of keys end up in multiple partition.

Now I am trying to find out why this is happening.

What are the common reason for key to be in multiple partition?

Comment: You could just calculate the partition values for your keys to prove your theory

Answer (score 0):

Adding a partition will change how keys are routed. So you can end up with messages with the same key being in two partitions. Before Key X used to go to Partition 5 but after the addition of one or more partitions it might go to Partition 3. Now you have Key X in partition 3 and 5. This is why you need to be very careful about your partitioning strategy.

Comment: But this is a one time thing right? If my partition count is the same i shouldn't be observing one key going to multiple partitions right?

Comment: Yes, a one time thing. I forgot to mention that you can always implement a custom partitioner and get round robin routing with keys and that would also lead to a key being routed to multiple partitions.

Comment: I should make it clear that it is the producer who chooses the partition. When using the default partitioner the producer will do round-robin when no key is involved and will route to specific partitions when a key is provided. But when producers use their own custom partitioners all bets are off.

Comment: I see, if there is custom partition involved, where is that logic at? In the `emitter.write` ?

Comment: Just to be clear, I am talking about a custom partitioner, not a custom partition. If there is a custom partitioner, then you'll find it in the producer. If you have control of the producers then check their code for any custom partitioner class. Other than those two reasons I have mentioned, I don't see why you'd see a key in multiple partitions.